# JAVA REGEX to find strings in double quotes that are within a line

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find the strings inside double quotes given a text file within a line. I have this regex
`\"([^\"]*)\"` which works fine. But for my scenario identify the strings that have the double quote starting in one line and ending in other line. for example,

```
"test
"
```

the above example is in two. so it should not print that. Please help me with a regex that identify strings in double quotes within a line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude line separators `\r` `\n` from accepted characters between quotes.
Try with `\"([^\"\n\r]*)\"`